# Python Dataframe: Transpose 4/5 Columns in a Dataframe And Hold Date Column Without Transposing

Tags: python, group-by, multiple-columns, transpose

I have a sample input dataframe:

| Name | Date | Score | Target | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | 2023-10-09 | 9 | 12 | 3 |
| Jim | 2023-10-16 | 13 | 16 | 3 |
| Andy | 2023-10-09 | 7 | 7 | 0 |
| Andy | 2023-10-16 | 5 | 20 | 15 |

Python code to create table:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':["Jim","Jim","Andy", "Andy"], 'Date':['2023-10-09', '2023-10-16', '2023-10-09', "2023-10-16"], 'Score':["9","13","7", "5"], 'Target':["12","16","7", "20"], 'Difference':["3","3","0", "15"]})
```

I want to transpose the above table by Name and have the rows be Date, Score, Target, and Difference.  The desired output table is below:

| Date | Category | Jim | Andy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-09 | Score | 9 | 7 |
|  | Target | 12 | 7 |
|  | Difference | 3 | 0 |
| 2023-10-16 | Score | 13 | 5 |
|  | Target | 16 | 20 |
|  | Difference | 3 | 15 |

I tried doing this with the code below but it doesn't produce the desired transposed table grouping by Date and Category columns.

```
df_2 =df.T
```

df_2 produces the following output which is transposing "Date" column which I don't want.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first melt your `"Score", "Target", "Difference"` columns into two key-value columns, and then apply `pivot`:

```
df \
    .melt(
        id_vars=["Name", "Date"],
        value_vars=["Score", "Target", "Difference"],
        var_name="Category"
    ) \
    .pivot(
        index=["Date", "Category"],
        values="value",
        columns="Name"
    )
```

Output:

```
Name                  Andy Jim
Date       Category           
2023-10-09 Difference    0   3
           Score         7   9
           Target        7  12
2023-10-16 Difference   15   3
           Score         5  13
           Target       20  16
```